# Spark-Submit read application.conf in cluster mode

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a jar which reads the typesafe config by

```
   object ConfigWordCount {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        // Load configuration into Settings class

        val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
                                              .appName("Word Count")
                                              .getOrCreate()
        val conf: Config = ConfigFactory.load()
        val settings: Settings = new Settings(conf)

        import spark.implicits._

        // Business logic
        val document = spark.read.textFile(settings.inputFile)
        val result   = document.flatMap(_.split(" "))
                               .filter(not(lower(col("value")).isin(settings.stopWords: _*)))
                               .groupBy("value")
                               .count()
                               .filter(col("count") >= settings.minCount)
                               .orderBy(desc("count"))
        result.coalesce(1).write.csv(settings.outputFile)

        spark.stop()
    }
}
```

I want to run my job in spark standalone cluster mode and pass the application.conf from the spark-submit.

By Far I have tried both client and cluster mode and

**Client**

```
spark-submit --master spark://xx.xx.xx.xx:6066 --deploy-mode client [...] --files application.conf --driver-java-options
-Dconfig.file=application.conf  myApplication.jar
```

**Cluster**

```
spark-submit --master spark://xx.xx.xx.xx:6066 --deploy-mode cluster  [...] --files application.conf --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dconfig.file=application.conf
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dconfig.file=application.conf s3a://bucket/myApplication.jar
```

The code works fine in the client mode and config is loaded, but in the **cluster mode**  it starts on one of the worker and fails by the error

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/centos/application.conf does not exist
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:611)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:824)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:421)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:1544)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:1508)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$13.apply(SparkContext.scala:462)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$13.apply(SparkContext.scala:462)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:462)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:935)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:926)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
```

Comment: can you post your code, how & where are you loading config file ? also can you post full exception ??

Comment: @Srinivas updates

Answer (score 1):

The difference between cluster and client is the node that the spark driver is hosted, in client mode, the driver is hosted in the same machine that executes the spark submit, in cluster mode it will be chosen by the spark cluster. This means that the driver can be reading the file in a different node that the one that has the config file.

Try to make a copy on each node, or use a mounted folder to make it easier.

The `--files` option is only valid for YARN